# Lambda@edge not triggered by an origin-request event

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying to configure Lambda@edge functions using CloudFormation. After deploying the template everything looks find in the console, however the lambda functions listening to `origin-request` events are not being triggered.
Strange enough, a `viewer-request` event does manage to trigger a function.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the `origin-request` event to work?

Here's my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Deployment of Lambda@edge functions

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - staging
      - production
    Default: staging
    Description: Stage that can be added to resource names
  CodeBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: The S3 Bucket name for latest code upload
  CodeKey:
    Type: String
    Description: The S3 Key for latest code upload

# Mappings:
#   AliasMap:
#     staging:
#       Alias: "staging-app.achrafsouk.com"
#     production:
#       Alias: "app.achrafsouk.com"
Resources:
  CFDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        Logging:
          Bucket: XXX.s3.amazonaws.com
          IncludeCookies: false
          Prefix: !Sub ${Stage}
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        Comment:
          !Sub "Lambda@Edge - ${Stage}"
          # Aliases:
          #   - !FindInMap [AliasMap,
          # Ref: Stage, Alias]
        Origins:
          - CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            DomainName: !Sub "${Stage}.defaultOrigin.example.com"
            Id: defaultOrigin
            OriginCustomHeaders:
              - HeaderName: X-Node-Env
                HeaderValue: !Sub "${Stage}"
          - CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            DomainName: !Sub "${Stage}.another.example.com"
            Id: rateLimitsOrigin
            OriginCustomHeaders:
              - HeaderName: X-Node-Env
                HeaderValue: !Sub "${Stage}"
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ForwardedValues:
            Headers:
              - CloudFront-Viewer-Country
              - X-Request-Host
              - User-Agent
            QueryString: true
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
          TargetOriginId: defaultOrigin
          DefaultTTL: 0
          MaxTTL: 0
          LambdaFunctionAssociations:
            # - EventType: viewer-request
            #   LambdaFunctionARN:
            #     Ref: ViewerRequestLambdaFunction.Version
            - EventType: origin-request
              LambdaFunctionARN:
                Ref: OriginRequestLambdaFunction.Version
        CacheBehaviors:
          - ForwardedValues:
              Headers:
                - CloudFront-Viewer-Country
                - X-Request-Host
                - User-Agent
              QueryString: true
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
            DefaultTTL: 60
            MaxTTL: 60
            TargetOriginId: rateLimitsOrigin
            PathPattern: "/rate-limit*"
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: origin-request
                LambdaFunctionARN:
                  Ref: GetRateLimitLambdaFunction.Version

  # ViewerRequestLambdaFunction:
  #   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  #   Properties:
  #     CodeUri:
  #       Bucket: !Sub ${CodeBucket}
  #       Key: !Sub ${CodeKey}
  #     Role: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn
  #     Runtime: nodejs10.x
  #     Handler: src/functions/viewerRequest.handler
  #     Timeout: 5
  #     AutoPublishAlias: live
  OriginRequestLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Sub ${CodeBucket}
        Key: !Sub ${CodeKey}
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: src/functions/originRequest.handler
      Timeout: 5
      AutoPublishAlias: live
  GetRateLimitLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Sub ${CodeBucket}
        Key: !Sub ${CodeKey}
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: src/functions/getRateLimit.handler
      Timeout: 5
      AutoPublishAlias: live

  LambdaEdgeFunctionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: "AllowLambdaServiceToAssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                - "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"

Outputs:
  # ViewerRequestLambdaFunctionVersion:
  #   Value: !Ref ViewerRequestLambdaFunction.Version

  OriginRequestLambdaFunctionVersion:
    Value: !Ref OriginRequestLambdaFunction.Version

  GetRateLimitLambdaFunctionVersion:
    Value: !Ref GetRateLimitLambdaFunction.Version

  CFDistribution:
    Description: Cloudfront Distribution Domain Name
    Value: !GetAtt CFDistribution.DomainName
```

Answer (score 14):

So, after painful hours of trial and error the solution was staring me in the face:
CloudFront distribution was emitting an error saying it could not connect to the origin, and it was right - because I've specified dummy domains in the origins definition of the CloudFront distribution.

My logic was that if my lambda@edge functions intercept the requests before reaching the origin, then it shouldn't matter if the origin's domains is real or not.

As it turns out, it's partially true. Because it seems that:

- `viewer-request` event is triggered before trying to connect to the origin, and therefore it can be fake.
- `origin-request` event is triggered only after trying to connect to the origin, so you'd need to specify something real.

Hope my wasted hours will contribute to someone else exploring the same path of reasoning.

Comment: your wasted hours much appreciated. had the exact same issue - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone in future with this problem - I noticed that `origin-response` (which I accidentally selected instead of `origin-request`) events were (mostly) working for me, but there were still a large number of `OriginConnectError` in the logs, and the "Percentage of Viewer Requests by Result Type" report was showing a high error rate.

It turns out it was only working at all because I had my origin connection set to `https-only`, but my origin (an empty s3 bucket) only accepted http connections - and for some reason the events were still being triggered.

Changing the origin connection to the correct `http-only` completely **stopped** things working for `origin-response`, until I also corrected the event type to `origin-request`

So, in general, check the OriginProtocolPolicy is `http-only` if you're using an s3 bucket origin. If it's wrong, things might still appear to work sometimes, but not always, and you'll end up with high error rates.